# How do i know how many bytes got transfered While uploading a file using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net

I am uploading large files using FtpWebRequest. Assume while uploading is in progress my network connection failed. How do I know how many bytes got transfered? When I restart uploading the same file I need to start uploading the file from where my connection was failed.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on the server if you can resume somewhere - so of course you have to provide the hole file again after a connection loss (just redo all your steps so far).
`FtpWebRequest` should handle all those details for you.

Aside from this you will get a [FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx)-Objekt from `GetResponse` with additional information